How to properly implement a custom-styled authentication button?
I need to add Google authentication to my website (Vue.js), which should be triggered by clicking a button.
I have the script: Script Link
Initialization:
window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: config.clientId,
  callback: (tokenResponse) => {
    if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.credential) {
      resolve(tokenResponse.credential);
    } else {
      console.error('Login with Google failed: No credential received');
      reject(new Error('Login with Google failed'));
    }
  },
});

After clicking the button, I make the call:
window.google.accounts.id.prompt()

But this method doesn't work if I close the One Tap window. It doesn't trigger again if I try to open it later.
If I use RenderButton, it offers too little customization for the button.
I found this authorization button constructor, but I don't understand why it's needed if I still can't link prompt to it so that it always triggers:
https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#expandable-1
Could you please explain how to properly implement a custom-styled authentication button?
